# Java RegEx: Replacing a phone number (including optional parentheses)

Tags: java, regex

Shouldn't this put the SPAN markers outside the phone number, not inside?

```
String aParagraph = "start 201-555-1212 more (301)-777-1212 again (401) 888-1212 end";
String phoneRegEx = "\\b(\\(?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}\\)?[- ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})\\b";
String replaceWith = "<span>$1</span>";

aParagraph = aParagraph.replaceAll(phoneRegEx , replaceWith);
```

Comment: The first group is the outer one, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word boundary, `\b`, matches a boundary of `\w+`. You can just remove them:

```
String aParagraph = "start 201-555-1212 more (301)-777-1212 again (401) 888-1212 end";
String phoneRegEx = "(\\(?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}\\)?[- ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})";
String replaceWith = "<span>$1</span>";

aParagraph = aParagraph.replaceAll(phoneRegEx, replaceWith);
```

Comment: It works fine without the \b.  But I thought I *HAD TO* have the 2 \b markers to ensure it avoided matching "this201-555-1212that".  No?  When *DO* I need the 2 \b markers?

Comment: @Carol: Come to think of it, I have never needed to use `\b` in regular expressions. But in this case, you're safe; `[1-9]` doesn't match `s` (at the end of `this`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of `\b`.  It considers the first number to be the start of the word boundary, not the `(`.  So it is actually matching:

```
301)-777-1212
```

And not

```
(301)-777-1212
```

as you intended.